# Fluent Migrator 1.1.1.0 wont apply migration

Tags: .net

I installed Fluent Migrator via Nuget... I created a basic migration

```
[Migration(1)]
class _001_User : Migration
{
    public override void Up() 
    {
        Create.Table("User");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Delete.Table("User");
    }
}
```

I run it with the runner and it creates the version table, but doesn't run this migration.  I used fluent migrator before and have no idea why this isn't working.  Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5, SqlServer2012

Output from fluent migrator runner.

```
VersionMigration migrating
[+] Beginning Transaction
[+] CreateTable VersionInfo
[+] Committing Transaction
[+] VersionMigration migrated
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VersionUniqueMigration migrating
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[+] Beginning Transaction
[+] CreateIndex VersionInfo (Version)
[+] AlterTable VersionInfo
[+] CreateColumn VersionInfo AppliedOn DateTime
[+] Committing Transaction
[+] VersionUniqueMigration migrated
[+] Task completed.
```

Comment: Try make migration class "public"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All migration classes should be public:

```
[Migration(1)]
public class _001_User : Migration
{
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it had to be something simple I was overlooking.